# How to join two UV maps pieces into one

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I don't understand how attach two UV maps pieces. Because,as you can see on the right side of the attached picture below,the mesh is not broken,but on the left side you can see that the Uv map is broken into two different pieces and I don't know how to join them. Really I don't understand the reason of this behaviour because I marked as seams all the edges in the front of the mesh. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: did you have all faces selected when you unwrapped? what method of unwrapping did you use? did you change some settings form the tool shelf (t) options while unwrapping?

Comment: no. When I do the unwrap I mark the seams ; I choose face select ; I select everything with A and then I press U,but sometimes it creates islands even if the seams there aren't anymore. check here : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-03-30_20-46-46.png ; I have cleared  the previous seams and I placed them in another place,but the old are still there and they are wrong !!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

---

Point 1, You **can** join seams.

Simply *select* the two vertices you would like to combine.

Then press <kbd>W</kbd>, then *"Weld"*. This will "join" those two vertices.

[image]

---

Point 2, **You NEED seams!**

Unwrapping requires cutting the model up into pieces (for it to work properly). Imagine it like you have a paper (3D) figure and you have to let it lay out flat. You must cut it enough times to do this. If you mark a seam, that will be a split. If you have marked all the seams you want and press <kbd>U</kbd>, then *"unwrap"*, it should unwrap with only your given seams, but after you mark a new seam, you must re-unwrap for it to take effect.

---

Point 3, Smart UV Project will automatically add new seams.

Smart UV Project is very automatic. It adds new seams where it deems best. This can be a problem if you are working with detailed unwraps. It is often easier to manually unwrap than welding seems left by Smart UV Project.

---

Point 4, You can do this for a whole seam.

Simply align the seams as best you can, then select them. (Tip, use proportional editing on "connected mode" to drag an edge closer to another while smoothly transforming the geometry in between.)

Then press <kbd>W</kbd>, then *"Align Auto"* to line up the two seams.

Now press <kbd>W</kbd> again (with both seams still selected) and click *"Remove Double UVs"*. This will remove the UVs that are next to each other. If you succeeded, this should merge your seams.

Note: If the vertices were too far apart after aligning, this will not work. You can do any necessary clean up using weld.

[image]

Here is a more complex join.

[image]